# eval not being executed in sync?

Tags: makefile

i have a faily simple build target such as

```
prod:
    packr
    mkdir -p build/public
    cp -r client/public/* build/public/
    minify -o build/public/index.html client/public/index.html
    minify -o build/public/app.js client/public/app.js
    minify -o build/public/normalize.css client/public/normalize.css
    gump patch -m "new release!"
    $(eval TAG=$(shell git tag -l --sort -version:refname | head -n 1))
    packr build -o build/pm -ldflags "-X main.Version=prod -X main.Tag=$(TAG)"
    rm -fr build/public
```

I m having issue with those three lines specifically

```
    gump patch -m "new release!"
    $(eval TAG=$(shell git tag -l --sort -version:refname | head -n 1))
    packr build -o build/pm -ldflags "-X main.Version=prod -X main.Tag=$(TAG)"
```

In plain text, it bumps GIT tags, get last version, build.

However for some reason i don t understand yet, `Makefile` assigns TAG=tagref-1, in other words, the previous version, not the newly built.

It behaves as if the variable was set before the bump has occurred.

I expected the TAG assignment to get the last tag number created with the previous bump command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rarely appropriate to use `make` functions in rules' recipes.  The issue (other than that functions are not portable to `make`s other than GNU's) is that functions are executed *when `make` reads the file*, whereas people using them in recipes tend to be looking for them to be executed when the recipe runs.  In some cases that doesn't make a difference, but yours is not one of those cases.

It's unclear what advantage you are seeking by assigning the new tag to a `make` variable instead of using it directly:

```
    gump patch -m "new release!"
    packr build -o build/pm -ldflags \
        "-X main.Version=prod -X main.Tag=$$(git tag -l --sort -version:refname | head -n 1)"
```

In that alternative, determining the current tag is deferred for the shell to do when it processes the `packr` command, so it will get the version as of that time.

If you need the tag to use elsewhere, too, then your best alternatives are probably:

- read the original version and *predict* the new one, maybe something like this:

  ```
  TAG = $(shell expr $$(git tag -l --sort -version:refname | head -n 1) + 1)
  ```
- add a new target to contain the computed version, and a rule to build it, and integrate that into your build
- determine the tag anew every time you need it (bumping it only the first time)